# search string and insert value in table

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.2

i have table having below records.The below product description are given by user in textbox in 
front end(asp.net).The product description will come with single quotes or double quotes.i want to insert in the table.so how can we check whether single quotes or double quotes are exists in the
the input and insert value in the table.please help.

String s=Textbook

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Details(Product_Description varchar(50))

    Required Output

    Product_Description
    -------------------
    STORE('COVERED)
    STEEL("ROOFED)
```

Insert statement will be differ for above two string?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly what you are looking for.  You should be able to store text with quotes or double quotes without any trouble (note, I'm testing on Postgresql 9.4, don't have 9.2).
The problem is sometimes creating the text with the single quotes.  In those cases it is common to have two single quotes like this `insert into product_details values ('STORE(''COVERED)')`  The double quotes (") should not be a problem.  You can use the syntax `E'STORE(\'COVERED)'` instead of the two quotes.  Sometimes more readable.

If you just want to check if there are ' or "" in the input, this check is convenient:

```
select length(replace(product_description,'''',''))!=length(product_description),   
length(replace(product_description,'"',''))!=length(product_description)
```

which return true/false columns telling if single-quote exists in string in first column and double-quote in the latter.

To delete the quotes in string you can do:
`select replace(replace(product_description,'"',''),'''','')`

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Don't build your SQL statement with string concatenation, make sure you bound variables. That way single or double quotes or any combination of them just becomes a value for the SQL engine to use and not part of the statement. (Also prevents SQL injection.) Further there is no difference in the statement, in fact it it the same statement. Hint of the day: Upgrade your Postgers version support/updates, even for security vulnerables, for it ended in Nov 2017.